# Messaging a forked child_process with just the pid

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have a main process spawning child_processes for long jobs.

I want to be able to poll the processes to get an update on the completion of the task, but all I have is their pid. How can I send a message to a specific process in nodejs?

Comment: It all depends on what the child processes are. Are you actually using `child_process.fork()`? It might help to show the code and tell what processes you're forking/spawning.

Comment: I am. After extended research it looks like I won't be able to retrieve it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `child_process.fork()` (*which I'm assuming you are*), you can send a message to the child process using `child.send()`: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle

There's no way to retrieve a child process object given a PID directly, however.